# Defparameter operation

Tags: common-lisp

Concerning the operation of `defparameter`--it looks like it only affects the symbol-value cell of the parameter:

```
> (defparameter *p* 16)
*P*

> (symbol-plist '*p*)
NIL

> (setf (symbol-plist '*p*) '(prop1 val1 prop2 val2))
(PROP1 VAL1 PROP2 VAL2)

> (defparameter *p* 16)
*P*

> (symbol-plist '*p*)
(PROP1 VAL1 PROP2 VAL2)
```

so the plist has not been reset to nil. Same kind of operation with the `symbol-function` cell, etc. This seems rather awkward, since reloading/compiling a file with `defparameter`s leaves the prior settings hanging around. Is there any convenient way to reset everything at once?

Comment: `DEFPARAMETER` just operates on variables. The property list is totally unrelated to its use as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what sds told you, if you `unintern` a symbol and introduce a fresh symbol with the same name, then you need to rebuild all the code that referenced the uninterned symbol so that it can refer to the new one. That's why it is impractical to use in production code, where recompiling things over and over would probably not be a good idea.

> Is there any convenient way to reset everything at once?

Just define a function and reset what you need to when appropriate:
Or, if you want it to happen only once after you call `defparameter`, you can do it too. 
Note that I would recommend clearing only the properties of the plist you control instead of getting rid of all its content. The environment might store some useful stuff there, like debugging information.

```
(defparameter *p* 16)

(eval-when (:compile-time :load-time :execute)
  (dolist (property '(prop-a prop-b prop-c))
    (setf (get '*p* property) nil)))
```

Edit:

I forgot about [`REMF`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_remf.htm):

```
(remf (symbol-plist '*p*) 'property)
```

The above removes the entry, whereas `(setf (get ...) nil)` binds the indicator to NIL.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can reset everything completely by [`unintern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_uninte.htm)ing the symbol:

```
[1]> (defparameter foo 10)
FOO
[2]> (defun foo (x) (1+ x))
FOO
[3]> (setf (get 'foo 'x) 'y)
Y
[4]> (symbol-plist 'foo)
(X Y SYSTEM::DEFINITION
 ((DEFUN FOO (X) (1+ X)) . #(NIL NIL NIL NIL ((DECLARATION OPTIMIZE DECLARATION)))))
[5]> (setq old-foo 'foo)
FOO
[6]> (unintern 'foo)
T
```

now the symbol is uninterned and when we re-create it with `read`, it has a "clean slate":

```
[7]> (fboundp 'foo)
NIL
[8]> (boundp 'foo)
NIL
```

but we can still access its slots via `old-foo`:

```
[9]> old-foo
#:FOO
[10]> (fdefinition old-foo)
#<FUNCTION #:FOO (X) (DECLARE (SYSTEM::IN-DEFUN #:FOO)) (BLOCK #:FOO (1+ X))>
```

PS. As Barry mentions in a comment, this might have unintended consequences and should be used with care. 
Specifically, this is a fine method while actively developing code. 
However, there should be no need for this "clean-up" operation in production.

Comment: This will do the desired reset, but it can have other implications. If there are references to the symbol in the same source file, they probably won't find the replacement symbol after you unintern.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, I should put the (unintern 'foo) right before the (defparameter 'foo ...) in the source file; and then wrap both in an eval-when to make sure the old cells aren't picked up at recompile time?

Comment: no, please read the PS. you should do that at the prompt while developing. this has no place in production code.

Comment: I assume it is safer to set things to `NIL` in production instead of uninterning them?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: If you have questions like that about production, you need to rethink your design.